# Displaying option selected from dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Trying something that sounds simple but not working:

Allow a user to select an option from a dropdownlist and then have this displayed as an alert each time the user changes it. Here's what I've got so far:

```
<select name="pickSort" id="chooseSort" onchange="changedOption">
    <option value="lowHigh" id="lowHigh">Price Low-High</option>
    <option value="highLow" id="lowHigh">Price High-Low</option>
</select>

<script>
function changedOption() {
    var sel = document.getElementsByName('pickSort');
    var sv = sel.value;
    alert(sv); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way of doing this without the inline stuff:

```
document.getElementById("chooseSort").onchange = function() {
  alert(this.value);
};
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wzm87/)

Comment: @user3389990 No worries - you did want the value and not the text inside, right? If you wanted the text, you'd use this - http://jsfiddle.net/Wzm87/1/.

Comment: That's fine for now. Now the next thing is to figure out how to use this in my JSP page! or even within a <% %> tags in that function

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function with parentheses `changedOption()`

```
 <select name="pickSort" id="chooseSort" onchange="changedOption()">
```

Comment: Oops, just noticed as you posted. I done that and now getting 'undefined' in the alert each time!

Comment: null answer is better, take he's ;)